# remove and recreate a mapview in a fragment android

Tags: android

am using the **android support v4- google maps by pete doyle** and am trying to delete a mapview and then recreate it again, when i go away from and return to it, but i keep getting the usual  **Java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity**. anyone know ho to solve this correctly. I have this code in my fragment.

Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate View called here in location fragment!!");

    if(view == null){
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);  

    frame = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
    //mapview = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    }

    if(mapview == null){

        mapview = new MapView(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.map_api_key));  // keep getting the error on this line
        mapview_is_active = true;
    }

    mapview.setClickable(true);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapview.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
    mapview.setStreetView(true); // Street View
    mapview.setTraffic(true); // Traffic View

    frame.addView(mapview,0);



    //frame = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);   
   return view;
}


  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       if(mapview == null){
           Log.d(TAG, "mapview is null here");
           mapview = new MapView(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.map_api_key));
       }

       if(frame.getChildAt(0) == null){
           Log.d(TAG, "mapview is null here in container");
           frame.addView(mapview);
       }

        MapController controller = mapview.getController();

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        double lon = Double.parseDouble(latitude);

        GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));

        mapview.invalidate();

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_point);
        AddMapOverlay add_map_overlay = new AddMapOverlay(drawable, getActivity());

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, name, address);

        add_map_overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(add_map_overlay);

        controller.animateTo(geopoint);
        controller.setZoom(15);
    }
```

and in my onStop():

```
 @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop(); 

        if(frame != null){
            frame.removeView(mapview); // i remove the mapview here
        }   
    }
```

here is my map.xml:

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>
```

any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Or perhaps try it in onPause()...

Comment: @logray you mean try initializing the MapView in onPause() ?

Comment: No try putting your frame.removeView(mapview) or .remooveAllViews in onPause instead of onStop.

Comment: @logray still getting the error there. do't know what else to do again

Comment: have you tried just calling mapview = null in the stop or pause?, after removing the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this with the below code. I have a MapView instance variable in my FragmentActivity, and then added and removed it in the Fragment itself below (just included the pertinent parts):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mLayoutMap = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layoutMap);

    // create the map view if it's not already there
    if (((MyActivity)getActivity()).mMapView == null)
    {
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).mMapView = 
                    new MapView(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.map_api_key));
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).mMapView.setClickable(true);
    }

    // add the map view to the frame layout, at the lowest z-index
    mLayoutMap.addView(((MyActivity)getActivity()).mMapView, 0);

}

@Override
 public void onStop()
 {
     super.onStop();

     if (mLayoutMap.getChildCount() > 0 && mLayoutMap.getChildAt(0) instanceof MapView)
         mLayoutMap.removeViewAt(0);
 }
```

mLayoutMap is just a FrameLayout in my XML.

Comment: Thank you!!!!.. you a life saver. thanks for taking the time. won't have thought of putting my mapview as an instant variable in the fragment activity. wondering how..?  Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

Usually I did this (use android-support-v4-google_maps as you):

1) Implement to activity interface like IMapActivity with methods of attachMap and detachMap

```
public class MyMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IMapActivity {
    private MapView mMapView;

    public void attachMap(ViewGroup mapHolder) {
        if (mMapView == null) {
            mMapView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.mapview, null);
        }

        mapHolder.addView(mMapView);
    }

    public void detachMap(ViewGroup mapHolder) {
        mapHolder.removeView(mMapView);
    }
}
```

2) Call that methods when need to attach MapView or detach MapView on Fragment.onDestroyView()

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {
    private IMapActivity mMapViewHolder;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mMapViewHolder = (IMapActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mMapViewHolder.attachMap(getMapHolder());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mMapViewHolder.detachMap(getMapHolder());
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

I keep in a separate xml MapView with the some settings. When it is necessary to destroy the Fragment - detach MapView, attach MapView when the Fragment is recreated (you can also update the controller of MapView after the attach). This allows me to reuse fragments MapView.

**P.S.**
I just have not found any way how to clean MapActivity of links to the MapViev. If there is a way, I would be very grateful.

Comment: thanks for the input but  i already have an FragmentActivity that holds fragments so it's quite difficult and late for me to change it now. i have to find a solution within the fragment for now.

Comment: If you do not require support API < 8, you can use new GoogleMap service API with its MapFragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using `frame.removeAllViews()`

Comment: but am still getting the error at the line where i initialize the mapview

Comment: Put a log and check that is your 'onStop()' method is called?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with navHost, you need to add it programmatically not in XML because it will be duplicated.

```
 val mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.mapFragment, mapFragment)
            .commit()
```