# Android Google Maps V2 Marker Ids not updating on fragment re-entry

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

I have a weird problem which didn't seem to be an issue until recently. I have a map fragment which adds markers to a map, and associates them with a java Map collection of **'<'marker id's, object they are associated with'>'** for the getInfoWindow call.

This works fine, 9 items are added to the map with ids m0-m8. However when I leave the fragment and re-enter it, the markers are added to the map with unique numbers again, so second time around the ids are m9-m17 etc.

The problem is that the marker's onInfoClick retains the old ids.

```
 CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        mWindow = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    }
@Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        //Here marker.getId() is usually always a value between m0-m8
        Business markerBusiness = mMarkersMap.get(marker.getId());

        //Render and do other things
        return mWindow();
}
```

How can I either force the addMarker() call to forget the id's from before OR make sure the new markers match the onInfoClick final marker ids? To further complicate things it seems this problem occurs only certain markers which I can't understand at all!

Let me know if more code is needed, I'm not sure what is necessary, I set a new infoWindowAdapter every-time the map fragment is recreated:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
//Add markers to the map

mMarkersMap.put(newMarker.getId(), business);
```

Comment: try with HashMap<Marker, MarkerModel>.just pass marker and you will get your model

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I do use a hash map, and the marker is fine the first time around, it's on re-entry to the map when the issue arises

Comment: create new has map with onCreateView method of Fragment.

Comment: Yes I do create a new map in the onCreateView every time, thank you but I don't think that was the problem. I think I have solved it, after a bit more searching I came across a couple of people mentioning that a new map is never actually created again if you specify it. E.g. Here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386865/google-maps-api-v2-multiple-map-fragment-problems), and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708747/remove-and-recreate-a-mapview-in-a-fragment-android). My solution is to clear() the GoogleMap object of all markers, that seems choose the correct final marker